# Why is NSScanner not finding the 1st occurrence of the target string?

Tags: objective-c, ios9.3, nsscanner

I have a Obj-c app that was working; now it isn't.  This is the portion of the string that I am trying to parse:

> <div class="PostContent"><div class="Article"><div class="Post"><div class="PostContent"> <div><img style="background-image: url('http://cdn.openisbn.com/images/no_book_cover.jpg');border: solid 1px #383c40; " src=/cover/0345377443_220.jpg width=220  border=0  title="Women Who Run With The Wolves:  Myths And Stories Of The Wild Woman Archetype"></div>Authors: <a href="/author/Clarissa_Pinkola_Estes/">Clarissa Pinkola Estes</a><BR>Publisher: <a href="/publisher/Ballantine_Books/">Ballantine Books</a>

Several thousand characters later, this text appears:

> <div class="block" id="LayoutColumn_3"><div class="blockTop"></div><h2</h2><div align="center"><a href="/isbn/006251380X/" ><img style="padding:1px;border:1px solid #6c6c6c; background-image: url('http://cdn.openisbn.com/images/no_book_cover.jpg');" src=/cover/006251380X_72.jpg width=72 height=114 border=0 title="The Faithful Gardener: A Wise Tale About That Which Can Never Die"></a><BR><a href="/isbn/006251380X/" >The Faithful Gardener: A Wise Tale About That Which Can Never Die</a><BR><a href="/isbn/1604076356/" ><img style="padding:1px;border:1px solid #6c6c6c; background-image: url('http://cdn.openisbn.com/images/no_book_cover.jpg');"

This is my code to find the title:

```
[scanner setScanLocation:0];
[scanner setCaseSensitive:NO];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" border=0 title=\"" intoString:nil];  //  title
scanner.scanLocation += 17;
[scanner scanUpToString:@"\">" intoString:&tempString];
oTitle.text = tempString;
```

What's happening is it is skipping the first occurrence (*Women Who Run...*) of the target string and finds the second occurrence (T*he Faithful Gardner*) and returns it rather than the first.  Since this used to work, and I haven't changed the code, can someone tell me why this is not working and possibly suggest some changes to the code to get it working again?  I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @rob no, I checked again and there are not two spaces between *border* and *title*, but thanks for the comments.  I'll read up on Ray's tutorial and see if it easily fits.  :D

Comment: @Rob please redo your comment about the double spaces; that was the problem!  I would like to give you points for the comment.  SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not finding the first occurrence is that that particular instance appears to have two spaces between `border=0` and `title="..."`:

```
<img style="..." src=... width=220  border=0  title="Women Who Run With ...">
```

Your scanner is looking for a string with only a single space.

---

Personally, I would suggest considering using an HTML parser. It's a little daunting the first time you use it, but it's an extremely powerful and flexible way of parsing HTML, and gets you out of the weeds of character-by-character scanning of the input. It's designed for precisely this sort of problem. See [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial on how to parse HTML](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

Comment: Thanks Rob... my code was correct; but the source had changed from a single space to a double space... you have good eyes!